# Why is the result completly different when I rotate the half circle instead of mirroring it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I watched  [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlxkDgZTLVY) and I wasnt able to reproduce the effect until I mirrored the half-circle. Why is that? It doesnt make sense for me.

Comment: So you can use blend to create all the other circles.

Comment: The reason is editability. If you make a shape with a gradient left to right and a drop shadow off lower left, when you rotate the shape the drop shadow and gradient remain in same direction. Because you're often dealing with uniform light source, all objects get same shadow direction no matter which way they're rotated. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paths, have a direction! One of the points is first and one of the points is last. When you rotate you end up with a different shape than by mirroring by point order. If you now blend midpoint to midpoint it assumes default direction and thus you get a different blend. The other you expect the other loops in on itself.

[image]